# Why no talk of n-level meta analyses instead of three-level meta-analyses?

Tags: multilevel-analysis, meta-analysis

I have a data set that I'm going to use for a meta-analysis that has a lot of dependencies between the effect sizes. Because of this, I've started to look into how people normally handle this, resulting in me finding a couple of articles (e.g. Konstantopoulos 2010; Cheung 2014) about three-level meta-analyses.

However, what puzzles me with all of these articles is that they're always talking about *three*-level meta-analyses rather than starting from the more general *n*-level meta-analyses. For my data set, I have what probably would count as a four-level structure (effect sizes clustered in testing occasions; testing occasions clustered into samples of participants; and samples of participants clustered into published papers) but I never find any examples of this in the literature. As of now, I'm [shifting the unit of analysis](https://books.google.se/books?id=sp3TBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA182&lpg=PA182&dq=shifting%20unit%20of%20analysis%20cooper&source=bl&ots=AKGMJcyP3U&sig=5aXczoB6TwPiRlXMFkR3KDBmb8I&hl=sv&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwixxq3AqOPMAhXMWSwKHZOMCtAQ6AEIMzAD#v=onepage&q=shifting%20unit%20of%20analysis%20cooper&f=false) by creating grand means on the sample level (meaning that I have several effect sizes for the same sample, corresponding to different factors of the certain moderator I'm interested in for the time being), and then I apply some kind of three-level analysis on *that* data, but I've never seen any examples of this in the literature either.

Am I missing something here?

**References**

- Cheung (2014). *Modeling dependent effect sizes with three-level meta-analyses: a structural equation modeling approach*. Psychological Methods, 2, 211-229.
- Konstantopoulos (2011). *Fixed effects and variance components estimation in three-level meta-analysis*. Research Synthesis Methods, 2, 61-76.

Comment: You can fit multilevel models with as many levels as you deem suitable for your data with `rma.mv()` in the `metafor` package in R.

Answer (score 3):

Since the multi-level meta-analytic models are special cases of the more general multi-level models then it must be possible to fit them. People have only recently started to publish articles about multi-level models in meta-analysis so I suspect the answer to your question lies in the fact that to need such a model and to be able to fit it demands a large number of primary studies and in many fields of scientific enquiry this is rare.

Comment: It may not be about the statistical theory. Substantive applications are usually lack behind methodological development. I have recently collaborated in a meta-analysis using a three-level meta-analysis where the three-level meta-analysis is clearly required in the data. The paper was declined for review by an editor because the paper was considered as "methodological" rather than "substantive."

Comment: @MikeCheung and if you submit it to a statistical journal they will say it is not sufficiently statistical. The woes of being ahead of the curve.